# Hibernate cfg file is not considering special characters in 'password' property

Tags: hibernate, mysql-8.0

I'm using Spring, **Hibernate 4.3** and **MySql-8** in my application. I use to connect to VPN to run the application. But in the hibernate configuration file when I give some '**special characters**' in
the password property it's not considering that and showing error. The same password is required to connect the MySQL db in VPN.

Below is the snap of hibernate-cfg.xml file:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://10.23.46.78:3306/fktpr</property>
<property name="connection.username">fktpr</property>
<property name="connection.password">^&gPLFNvuk?3Xd^YDj</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
```

In the above snap, the password line is showing error like;

> The reference to entity "gPLFNvuk" must end with the ';' delimiter.

The string above is the *partial DB password* `^&gPLFNvuk?3Xd^YDj` string which is mentioned in error and it's cutting off the special characters `&`, `?` and `^`. How can I resolve this problem? The whole password will be required to connect the DB in VPN.

Comment: No one have any comments/ answer for this?? :( Is there any other way to set the properties,, like using **property file** or something so that it's not throw any error?? Or any **escape character** to handle this kind scenario??

Comment: In the password string, can you try HTML encoding it, for example, `^&gPLFNvuk?3Xd^YDj` would become - `^&amp;gPLFNvuk?3Xd^YDj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to escape the special characters in xml -

```
& --> &amp;

< --> &lt;

> --> &gt;
```

`^&gPLFNvuk?3Xd^YDj` would become - `^&amp;gPLFNvuk?3Xd^YDj`